# Mitosis in free nuclear divisions

Tags: mitosis, cell-division

When free nuclear divisions occur(for instance in endosperm formation in coconut etc)....there are many nuclei undergoing kartokinesis at a given point of time...so that means each karyokinesis will naturally have to involve spindle fibre formation for the chromosomes to be pulled apart in anaphase....so when there are no cell walls or barriers and so many sets of spindle fibres...how is it that the spindle fibre of say dividing nucleus 1 doesn't go and attack to the chromosome of another dividing nucleus....shouldn't there be utter chaos out there as every spindle fibre can attach to any chromosome of any diving nucleus.....I hope you have u der stood my question

Comment: No one knows about this?